# Deleted around 10GB of files while sleeping, can't find out what's been deleted

Tags: windows-10

I left my laptop open while i was asleep, and woke up to a halfway-completed progress bar for file deletion. The recycle bin was empty, and upon checking my C:\ folder, i noticed it was 10GB lighter. None of the stuff i usually use seems to have been deleted, and i'm worried that system files may have been damaged instead. if i need to, i can still access the files from a dual-booted ubuntu so that isn't so much an issue, but i also worry that if windows fails to boot and tries to restore itself, it may overwrite ubuntu and ruin both systems. is there a way to get the files back if i don't know what's been deleted in the first place?

Comment: The standard answer is "restore from your backups". Let this be a lesson and start making them. File loss is common. There are so many people with issues that would be non-issues with backups that I'm considering preparing some response templates. (Locking your computer when not using it is also a good habit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a disk recovery software, this will scan your disk and find files which was deleted and accessible to recover. The list can be sorted by deleted date in this way you will get an idea what kind of files was deleted in last few hours.

Comment: sorry about the late response, i've done it and everything seems to work well. thank you for the help :)